# Creating a Range and saving as a named range in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to define a range with a name that can be referenced in a formula in the spreadsheet. This range needs to be defined using a macro, as it is dynamic.

I have some data that is manually added based on test results. Depth (y-axis) over time (x-axis). This means that some of the rows won't have a depth filled in. 
I then want to automatically calculate the exponential curve that best fits the data. I do this using the following formulas to get the components of the graph function:

```
=EXP(INDEX(LINEST(LN(Yvalues),"Xvalues"),1,2))
=INDEX(LINEST(LN(Yvalues, "Xvalues"), 1)
```

This formula does not work if the data contains any 0 values.

I have some dynamic code that creates a copy of the data without the rows that don't have y values. This updates with the data that is manually entered, which means the number of rows also changes.

I somehow need to define a dynamic range that is always the same length as the summarised data which can be referenced in the above formulas.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Range("B2:C23").AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Range("B26:C27"), _
    CopyToRange:=Range("E2:F23"), _
    Unique:=False
End Sub`
```

EDIT:

This is the code I started writing to do the above but I know it's going to take me far to long to make it actually work.

```
Sub Sorting_x()
Dim Xlong As Range
Dim Xshort As Range
Set Xlong = Range("E3:E23")
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Dim myRangeNamex As String

myRangeNamex = "Xshort"

For i = 1 To 23
    If Xlong.Range.Cells(i, 1) > 0 Then
    Set Xshort.Range.Cells(i, 1) = Union(Xshort, Xlong.Range.Cells(i, 1))
    End If
Next i

ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=mRangeNamex, RefersTo:=Xshort

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. You copy filtered data to E2 and you want to refer to the number of rows of data there in your formula? Why not add the formula in your code?

Comment: I want to display the results of the formula in my worksheet. And I don't know how to identify how many rows the E2 data has as it changes all the time... I'm happy to put the formula in my code, but don't know how to then print the results.

Comment: Do you really want your code to run every time any cell is selected?

Comment: I basically want the entire workbook to update once new data has been added. This is for other people to use, so they can see the outputs of their data without messing with the spreadsheet. The real issue here is that the data plots to an exponential function and that fundamentally won't work if data with zeros is included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r As Range, rX As Range, rY As Range

Range("B2:C23").AdvancedFilter _
                    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                    CriteriaRange:=Range("B26:C27"), _
                    CopyToRange:=Range("E2"), _
                    Unique:=False

Set r = Range("E3", Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'omit header
Set rX = r.Columns(1)
Set rY = r.Columns(2)

Range("A1").Formula = "=EXP(INDEX(LINEST(LN(" & rY.address & ")," & rX.address & "),1,2))"
Range("A2").Formula = "=INDEX(LINEST(LN(" & rY.address & ", " & rX.address & "), 1)"

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks good thanks! Would you mind updating it with the formula in my original Q? I'm not sure how to reference within "r", within the formula. So the "Xvalues" are the first column (minus the first row) and the "Yvalues" are the second column (minus the first row).

Comment: Amended above. Not sure I've got your ranges right but hopefully you can work out the logic. I would suggest not putting this in a selectionchange event though.

Comment: Great thanks. I was so close. I'm not very familiar with the address syntax for ranges.